# How to compile a .NET application for CPU optimization?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation

I have a .NET C# application which should be run only on one computer with known configuration (HP DL120 G7, Xeon E3-1220, Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation if this is important). I don't need to run this application on other computers.

I want to:

- make it as fast as possible (i.e. probably compile with "use Xeon E3-1220" key or something?)
- secure it **a little bit** (it should not be trivial to restore C# source code from binaries).

Should I compile to native Windows code somehow? Probably I should use some special compiler options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile it in "Release" mode to enable optimizations. Also, you can run [ngen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx) to generate native DLLs which will not incur the overhead of JIT.

However, keep in mind that all these measures and tools are not a silver bullet for a poorly written code (not saying that yours is). You should profile your app and see if you can improvise the execution time of any code path as well as find out the slower paths (and seek to improve them).

To secure it, use a good obfuscator such as (Salamander, SmartAssembly etc.). It won't be entirely indiscernible but it'll make it lot more harder.

To ***absolutely*** secure it, code it in C++! You can compile it with `/clr` option which will make them [immune to reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0114hz2.aspx) and disassembly.

Comment: so if i'm not care about start-up time, but I'm care only about "execution" time I do not need ngen? Can I compile somehow the code to use on target platform for maximum optimization? (hm or probably .net runtime will do that for me)

Comment: Well, there are additional benefits such as a smaller working set and image sharing between _processes_. Jitted assemblies cannot be shared as they are private to the AppDomain. There are some caveats too, I suggest you read up this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx) article to get a full understanding.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to restore code from .Net assemblies.  You can go some way by obfuscating the contents (google for this).

As for compilation, the CLR will compile it efficiently when the process is started - you shouldn't have to worry about this.  If the startup time is high, you can use ngen (AOT compiler) to compile your assembly:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Image_Generator

If you want to make sure it's fast, make sure you compile in release mode though, with optimisations (it will be in your project properties).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx) to create and cache optimized native images of your assemblies.